# What is appStoreReceiptURL exactly for?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

The documentation doesn't say what `appStoreReceiptURL` exactly is ( i mean `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`). My current suggestion - it is the receipt for last performed IAP incomplete transaction.
But what if we have multiple incomplete transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, looks like I've found the answer (experimentally). 
The receipt file at path returned by `appStoreReceiptURL` method contains all receipts ever issued by Apple for particular application. Moreover, it contains even those purchases that were made on other devices with the same AppleId.